# Trouble with Dojo Build and Conversion to AMD

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I'm working on a Dojo application written by someone else.  I'm new to Dojo, but have discovered that to reduce http requests i need to produce a "build" version.  This i have done, AFAICT (i get a single compressed script at least), but when using the built script, none of the functions previously available work (they're "undefined").

Furthermore, in trying to figure this out, it looks as though this would be a good point to make the code AMD compatible (is this code AMD compatible?).  How would this work with examples such as the one below?  From reading it appears that i might need to make each existing function from scripts like this into a module, which would produce hundreds of scripts, and doesn't feel right.  How best to convert code such as this so that it will be AMD compatible and buildable?

I've got 15 or so .js scripts all containing varying numbers of functions written this way...

TIA!

```
var somethingStatus = false;

somethingInit();

function somethingInit() {

    require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/cookie", "dojo/json", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ready, dom, domConstruct) {

        ready(function() {

            var content = '';
            // content generated here, then...

            domConstruct.place(content, dom.byId('body'));

        });

    });

}

function somethingToTop(target) {

    require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/window", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, domStyle, fx, win) {

        var vs = win.getBox();

        somethingBarStatus = true;

        fx.animateProperty({
            node: dom.byId('somethingBar'),
            properties: {
                top: { start: domStyle.get('somethingBar', 'top'), end: 0 },
                height: { start: domStyle.get('somethingBar', 'height') + (domStyle.get("somethingBar", "padding") * 2), end: vs.h }
            },
            duration: 500,
            onEnd: function() {
                document.location = 'http://192.168.0.1' + target;
            }
        }).play();

    });

}

function somethingEmptyTop() {

    require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, domConstruct) {

         globalContainerEmpty('somethingTop'); // this function is in another .js file, constructed similarly to this

    });

}

// many more functions like this below and across other scripts!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a common problem when migrating from pre-AMD Dojo to Dojo 1.7, in that many people would attempt to run scripts through the build that are entirely not modules.  The Dojo build tool is really designed to accommodate modules, not loose scripts, but this sort of thing happened to "Just Work" before.

In the example above, you have a script that seems to just define a number of global functions.  If anything, it's the inverse of a proper module, since each individual function involves its own `require` call.

When the Dojo build encounters a file that it detects isn't already in AMD format, it puts an AMD wrapper around it, with the purpose of adapting proper legacy Dojo modules that use `dojo.provide`, `dojo.require`, and global namespaces like `dojo` and `dijit`.  The problem is, when these "global" functions in your script are wrapped, they become local to the `define` factory in the wrapper, and are thus no longer global.

A proper conversion of the code above would look something like this:

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/fx',
    'dojo/cookie',
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/dom-construct',
    'dojo/dom-style',
    'dojo/json',
    'dojo/window',
    'my/otherModule',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function (fx, cookie, dom, domConstruct, domStyle, JSON, win, otherModule) {

    var somethingStatus = false;

    var util = {
        somethingInit: function () {
            var content = '';
            // content generated here, then...

            domConstruct.place(content, dom.byId('body'));
        }

        somethingToTop: function (target) {
            var vs = win.getBox();

            somethingBarStatus = true;

            fx.animateProperty({
                node: dom.byId('somethingBar'),
                properties: {
                    top: { start: domStyle.get('somethingBar', 'top'), end: 0 },
                    height: { start: domStyle.get('somethingBar', 'height') + (domStyle.get("somethingBar", "padding") * 2), end: vs.h }
                },
                duration: 500,
                onEnd: function() {
                    document.location = 'http://192.168.0.1' + target;
                }
            }).play();
        },

        somethingEmptyTop: function () {
            // assuming that the other module was converted similarly to this one
            otherModule.globalContainerEmpty('somethingTop');
        }
    };

    util.somethingInit();
    return util;
}
```

- Notice that all of the dependencies formerly in each individual function have been collected in the `define` call for this module.
- `dojo/ready` is generally not needed with AMD since dojo/domReady! already waits for `DOMContentLoaded` (or equivalent), and the `define` factory already waits until modules are loaded.

You would then be able to access each of the functions on this module by loading it via `define` in another module or `require` in a page script, then referencing the functions via the variable you store the module in.  (In this example, `otherModule` is an example of using another converted module, since you suggested that `globalContainerEmpty` is in another similar script file.)

The [modules tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/) can hopefully provide further help, and possibly also the [modern Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modern_dojo/) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. That actually makes some kind of sense (to me) and has given me some renewed enthusiasm!

Comment: Looking over the Dojo modules tutorial - is there a particular difference between your example where you wrap functions in 'var util = {...}' and use 'util = somethingInit();', and wrapping in a return{...} instead?

Comment: Oops, that looks like a typo in my example.  I meant to do `util.somethingInit();` to run that immediately like what your example did, then `return util;`.  I'll fix that.  (That's the only reason I made a variable, so I could self-reference it.)